# Spring JPA Repository query for JSON_CONTAINS

Tags: mysql, json, spring, jpa

A working query:

```
SELECT * from session WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(old_callback_codes,'"OLD-CODE"')
```

This is what I have tried with a Spring Repository

@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "SELECT * from session WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(old_callback_codes,?1)")

which produces:

```
SELECT * from session WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(old_callback_codes,'OLD-CODE')
```

Any idea how to get the extra quotation marks inserted? I have tried a few ideas but cannot get it.

Comment: Pass them in the method as an argument. Spring will put the string you put in as is into the variable. So you didn't include it why should Spring include it.

Comment: Makes sense, all sorted